# Can you pass property values into a 'Specific Page' URL path in the Web Properties in C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, localhost, webapi

I am working on a program to GET data from an API.

I am having an issue with error 404, which I resolved by setting the Web Property on the Web application to the name of the controller(rating), and the name of the method (index.)

[image]

Is this best way to deal with 404?

Also,

I need to pass these property values into the URL, how do I do this working alongside the above fix?

[image]

Thank you

Comment: 1. What are you doing to get a 404 and what does your controller action look like? Setting "specific page" as startup page doesn't really solve anything. 2. Don't post code as an image.

Comment: My controller class is RatingController. I fixed the specific page startup by changing the Map Route to
defaults: new { controller = "Rating", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }

from
defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }

however, I now need to pass in the ID to the URL

Answer (score 0):

Look like you in debug mode on the web app. Thats why setting the specific start page to rating/index solve your 404. For debugging API app this is fine. To have another app GET data from this API app you need to invoke the API app this way:

```
<URL of the API app>/rating/index
```

e.g.

```
https://myAPIapp.com/rating/index
```